# How to merge dataframes by two columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have two dataframes. The first one contains data about orders: df_1 with columns ['uid','revenue','order_day'] which has 50415 rows. And the second one contains info about visits: df_2 with columns ['uid','source','session_day'] with 358532 rows. I want to get the source of customer from dataframe of visitors. I am trying to merge dataframes by two columns: `result = df_1.merge(df_2, how=left ,left_on=['uid','order_day'],right_on=['uid','session_day'])` But in result I get 62369 rows and the sum of `'revenue'` column increases. I don't understand why this is happening. When I write `how='left'` I expect that the left df_1 will be unchanging, and the rows which are similar both in `'uid'` and `'..._day'` from the df_2 will be added. Can someone explain me why I don`t get expected result, and what I should do for it? Will be thankful for any comments

Comment: There can be some duplicate rows in df2 or df1 and this may be the reason for this behaviour.Can you please check if the combination of the keys are unique across both dataframes ?

Comment: Please create a workable reproducible code of your problem, a simple representation so someone can test how to solve it. And in that sample show what is your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of rows in the merge result exceeding the number of rows in *df_1*
can be explained on the following example:

**df_1** contains 2 rows:

```
   uid  revenue   order_day
0  111   200.01  2019-09-01
1  111   300.00  2019-09-02
```

**df_2** contains 5 rows:

```
   uid  source session_day
0  111   100.0  2019-09-01
1  111   200.0  2019-09-01
2  111   300.0  2019-09-02
3  111   400.5  2019-09-02
4  222   100.0  2019-09-03
```

Note that it contains:

- Two rows with *uid == 111* and *session_day == 2019-09-01*,
  which will be merged with row with index *0* in *df_1*.
- Two rows with *uid == 111* and *session_day == 2019-09-02*,
  which will be merged with row with index *1* in *df_1*.

This is why the result of merge is:

```
   uid  revenue   order_day  source session_day
0  111   200.01  2019-09-01   100.0  2019-09-01
1  111   200.01  2019-09-01   200.0  2019-09-01
2  111   300.00  2019-09-02   300.0  2019-09-02
3  111   300.00  2019-09-02   400.5  2019-09-02
```

Probably you assumed that the merge is executed the following way:

- Take a row from *df_1*.
- Look in *df_2* for a **single** row with matching join columns.
- If found, add the merge result (for these 2 rows) to the result.
- Repeat the whole procedure for following rows from *df_1*.

Actually, the "left" merge is performed **other way**:

- Take a row from *df_1* (let's call it *base row*).
- For **each** row from *df_2* with matching join columns (if any found)
  generate a row in the result, composed of:

  - content from the base row (from *df_1*),
  - content of the current row (from *df_2*).

If you want to have merge of each row from *df_1* with **at most 1 row**
from *df_2*, you must start with *drop_duplacates* from *df_2*, with *subset*
containing the merge columns.